# AngularJS ng-repeat, highlight new element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I have an application that polls the server via ajax and adds the json to an ng-repeat.

I'd like to know how I can highlight the latest entry to the list?

```
<div id="activity-listing" ng-controller="activityListing">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in activity track by task.id | orderBy:'task.id':true" class="activity-item">
            <div class="activity-person">{{ task.name }}</div>
            <div class="activity-type">{{ task.activity }}</div>
            <div class="activity-time" am-time-ago="task.time"></div>
            <div class="activity-location">{{ task.location }}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you apply a class based on $first ?

Comment: why won't you use the css selector ul li:last-child ? lighter than angular solutions

Comment: Is it possible to add a class to the new items in the list i.e. those that aren't replaced by track by? So that as the list updates from the ajax polling only new items are highlighted. Rather than just highlighting the last item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$last` and then apply a CSS animation on it.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

`ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"`

```
<div id="activity-listing" ng-controller="activityListing">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in activity track by task.id | orderBy:'task.id':true" class="activity-item" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}">
            <div class="activity-person">{{ task.name }}</div>
            <div class="activity-type">{{ task.activity }}</div>
            <div class="activity-time" am-time-ago="task.time"></div>
            <div class="activity-location">{{ task.location }}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```